# ERD design to keep a record of changes made by users

Tags: sql, database-design, relational-database, data-warehouse, erd

I am trying to design the ERD Schema for a small project. It is a loan business that tracks loans (Amounts, interest, to whom, repayment date, etc etc.) This is what i have so far, if you have any suggestions that would be great. But my main question is:

How do i track changes made to loans? For instance, a Lender changes the date that the repayment needs to be made by, I would normally just go into the DB and update the date value. However, now i want to be able to have a record of what the original value(date) was. Or someone with an existing loan takes out another loan, do i then make a new record in the Loan table with the combined values? and how can i store what the original value loaned was, and what the new amount is?

I think i maybe need some kind of DW? let me know what you think. Cheers

[image: Current ERD diagram]

Answer (score 0):

> How do I track changes made to loans?

Create a Loan Adjustment table.  You would put both the interest rate and repayment date in the adjustment row, whether one or both columns were adjusted.

You'll have to check if one or more adjustment rows exist whenever you SELECT the Loan row.  If you just want the most recent adjustment, add a WHERE MAX(Modified Timestamp).

```
Loan Adjustment
---------------
Loan Adjustment ID
Loan ID
Borrower ID
Lender ID
Modified Interest Rate
Modified Repayment Date
Modified Timestamp
```

> Or someone with an existing loan takes out another loan, do I then
> make a new record in the Loan table with the combined values?

No.  You create a new loan row in the Loan table with a new Loan ID.  You can create an index on the Borrower ID in the Loan table and see if the borrower has more than one loan.

No, you don't need a data warehouse, unless you want to have a place to keep loans that have either been repaid or defaulted.  Active loans belong in an operational relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the above answer, but I would create a Loan Header table and a Loan Details table. The Header table would hold the unchanging elements and the Detail would hold the changeable elements + FK to the Header, an effective date field and, possibly, a Current Flag